# Having trouble fetching MongoDB using React on Meteor

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I'm trying to build a todo app on Meteor using the new React (which is basically like learning Meteor all over again).

Anyway, I'm trying to load MongoDB data on top of this `ListBox` React component and using this data as props via `this.props.lists`, but when console logging the `this` and navigating to the props key, there are no props and nothing I insert to the MongoDB shows up for some reason.

Here is the code:

```
import React, {PropTypes} from "react";
import {List} from "./list.jsx"
import {Lists} from "/imports/api/database.js";
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

export class ListBox extends React.Component{

_renderTasks(){
  return this.props.lists.map((list) => (
    <List key={list._id} task={list}/>
  ))
}

  render(){
    console.log(Lists.find({}).fetch())
    return(
      <div class="ui raised very padded text container segment">
      <div className="ui inverted segment">
        {this._renderTasks()}
</div>
</div>
    )
  }
}


export default createContainer(() => {
  return {
    lists: Lists.find({}).fetch()
  };
}, ListBox);
```

There is no error code in my console. All packages are installed, including `react-meteor-data` for rendering reactive data to react components.

Comment: Do you have "autopublish" installed? Because I see no subscriptions in your code.

Comment: Yeah, autopublish is installed.

Comment: I am also following the simple TODO example, i am not getting any data inside the CreateContainer.

https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/collections